# Can't find the word erfolgen in the dictionary

Tags: dictionary

I can't find many verbs in the German-English dictionary.

The word used was `erfolgte` and I've been looking for `erfolgen` in the dictionary, but it is not there. I doubt that it's the dictionary, but is it the right word to look up?

I'm having trouble finding verbs in general.

Comment: Conclusion, with regards to the comments below: You need a new (=larger, more words) dictionary ;-)

Comment: Or use online dictionaries. http://mobile.pons.com/dict/search/mobile-results/?l=deen&q=erfolgen#results

Comment: And  try dict.leo.org .

Answer (score 5):

`erfolgen` = to happen, to occur

see this dictionary http://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=erfolgen&iservice=

Comment: Or use Leo: https://dict.leo.org/?lp=ende&lp=frde&search=erfolgen&searchLoc=0&relink=on&spellToler=standard&cmpType=relaxed

Comment: And some prefer [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=erfolgen).

Comment: Or [Pons](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=erfolgen&l=deen&in=&lf=en)

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erfolgen

Comment: https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/erfolgen#erfolgen_.28Deutsch.29

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/erfolgen#German

Comment: https://translate.google.de/m/translate#de/en/erfolgen

Comment: http://dreiartikel.de/dictionary/?q=erfolgen&ddir=de (Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your dictionary lists *erfolgen* as a sub-entry of *folgen*?
If this is the way your dictionary is structured, [canoo.net/wordformation](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation) could help you to identify the word stems you need to look up in your dictionary.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Personally, I would doubt that *erfolgen* and *folgen* share a dictionary entry anywhere but never say never …

Comment: @Jan Yes, it's very unlikely, but not impossible :) Thanks for the edit!

Comment: German (and Yiddish) dictionairies drive me crazy because the same verb is in 10 different places depending on the prefix. So when I published a transcription of a Yiddish memoir ten years ago,  I organized the glossary the way I thought it should be...one root vert, with all the prefixes as sub-entries under the root. Sure enough, DERFOLG (all German er- words appear as der- words in Yiddish) is a sub-entry under FOLGEN. You can see my glossary at this link...it includes the last chapter of the memoir, plus the glossary.  Here is the pdf link:  http://www.onforeignsoil.com/pdf/Glossary.pdf

Comment: @Marty Green wow, what an effort. Thanks for sharing. I guess,  a dictionary like that works well, if you recognise the root. It would be quite  painful for a new learner :)